# There is no postgresql14-llvmjit-* for postgres on redhat8 ppc64le

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install postgres 14 on redhat 8 ppc64le architecture, I'd like to install package llvmjit, but I could not find such a package in https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/14/redhat/rhel-8-ppc64le/, while for postgres 14 on redhat 8 x86_64 architecture, there are such packages postgresql14-llvmjit-* in https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/14/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64/

I wonder if there any changes to llvmjit for postgres 14 on redhat 8 ppc64le architecture? why postgres does not provide

Comment: [Subscribe](https://lists.postgresql.org/) to the pgsql-pkg-yum mailing list and ask there. Only Devrim knows.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you very much, I did not know there is such a mailing list before.